# Rapid development tools/IDE

Tags: wysiwyg

> IDE/tools which facilitate a user to
>   develop an application without codding
>   but just some drag & drop generally
>   fails to achieve good performance.
>   Even though they are highly required
>   by small organizations/companies,
>   freelancer, and the people who are
>   always busy to some R&Ds.

Successful areas where generally whole work can be done with some drag&drop manner or using a wizard are,

1. Web Page designing
2. Graphics design
3. Flash based game like creating
   comics & super heros etc :)
4. CMS theme designer/creater (eg [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/))
5. Websites using CMS like wordpress

Even though there are many addon/extensions/plugins are available which can complete most of the part of your work, they don't know what exactly we need.

**My question** after all this blah blah..

Initially i was asking "Is there any application for rapid developement of android application using simple drag&drop". Now I am *generalizing my question to all languages & all areas*.

Since any development required some portion of coding. But i believe that specific type of applications, which follow common pattern, can be developed by WYSIWYG type IDEs.Like

1. Converting an application from one
   programming language to another
   successfully.
2. Creating reference libraries for
   mobile (like [jquery reference](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.whawhawhat.referencejquery&feature=search_result))
3. [Flash cards](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teachersparadise.abcflashcardsforkids)
4. [fact or tip&tricks book](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ximad.wff_lite&feature=search_result) etc etc.

Please suggest tool which can help to develop such applications by putting input data instead of codding.

*I took max reference from android market just to complete this question earlier.

*R&D - Research & Development

Answer (score 1):

For android application development, [Appinventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/) is best choice. Moreover you can go for [freeandroidappmaker](http://freeandroidappmaker.com/) too.

One more software i found is [Basic4Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/). This is best application for Visual Basic user. Now they need not to switch to java.

I'll add more tools or online services if i find.

Comment: I tried AppInventor. Although i'll have to learn its usage, i seems perfect. I'll wait to accept an answer..thanks